# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app' on Heroku

Tags: git, flask, heroku, web-applications

I'm trying to deploy a machine learning model to a web app. I created a functioning web app using Flask and Jupyter but it's currently running on my local machine. I want to use Heroku to deploy the flask app so other people can use my web app  as well.

My app folder looks like this:

```
webapp/
    ├── model/
    │   └── alert_model.pkl
    ├── templates/
    │   └── home.html
    ── static/css
    │   └── style.css
    ├── requirements.txt
    ├── Procfile
    └── app.ipynb
```

I've written the following in the command line:

```
git init
heroku login 
heroku create alert-model (The name of my model)
git add .
git commit -m "First commit!"
heroku git:remote -a alert-model
git push heroku master
```

It doesn't show any error upto this point but when I write `heroku open` it throws an error.

I checked the Heroku logs and saw a `"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'"` error. Is it talking about the app.py file?

Heroku Logs:

```
2020-06-15T16:57:22.842434+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn app:app`
2020-06-15T16:57:25.527630+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-06-15 16:57:25 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
2020-06-15T16:57:25.528337+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-06-15 16:57:25 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:31744 (4)
2020-06-15T16:57:25.528470+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-06-15 16:57:25 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2020-06-15T16:57:25.532977+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-06-15 16:57:25 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2020-06-15T16:57:25.539161+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-06-15 16:57:25 +0000] [10] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2020-06-15T16:57:25.539163+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-06-15T16:57:25.539164+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2020-06-15T16:57:25.539164+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2020-06-15T16:57:25.539165+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
2020-06-15T16:57:25.539165+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2020-06-15T16:57:25.539165+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
2020-06-15T16:57:25.539166+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2020-06-15T16:57:25.539167+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2020-06-15T16:57:25.539167+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2020-06-15T16:57:25.539168+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
2020-06-15T16:57:25.539168+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2020-06-15T16:57:25.539168+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
2020-06-15T16:57:25.539169+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2020-06-15T16:57:25.539169+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
2020-06-15T16:57:25.539170+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2020-06-15T16:57:25.539170+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
2020-06-15T16:57:25.539171+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2020-06-15T16:57:25.539171+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
2020-06-15T16:57:25.539172+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
2020-06-15T16:57:25.539175+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2020-06-15T16:57:25.539180+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'
2020-06-15T16:57:25.539336+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-06-15 16:57:25 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2020-06-15T16:57:25.569897+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-06-15 16:57:25 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2020-06-15T16:57:25.570043+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-06-15 16:57:25 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2020-06-15T16:57:25.642627+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2020-06-15T16:57:25.690176+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-06-15T16:57:25.692916+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-06-15T16:57:30.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-06-15T16:57:34.119599+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn app:app`
2020-06-15T16:57:36.630415+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-06-15 16:57:36 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
2020-06-15T16:57:36.631266+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-06-15 16:57:36 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:48932 (4)
2020-06-15T16:57:36.631426+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-06-15 16:57:36 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2020-06-15T16:57:36.637562+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-06-15 16:57:36 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2020-06-15T16:57:36.643834+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-06-15 16:57:36 +0000] [10] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2020-06-15T16:57:36.643835+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-06-15T16:57:36.643836+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2020-06-15T16:57:36.643836+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2020-06-15T16:57:36.643836+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
2020-06-15T16:57:36.643837+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2020-06-15T16:57:36.643837+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
2020-06-15T16:57:36.643837+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2020-06-15T16:57:36.643838+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2020-06-15T16:57:36.643838+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2020-06-15T16:57:36.643838+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
2020-06-15T16:57:36.643838+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2020-06-15T16:57:36.643839+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
2020-06-15T16:57:36.643839+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2020-06-15T16:57:36.643839+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
2020-06-15T16:57:36.643839+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2020-06-15T16:57:36.643840+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
2020-06-15T16:57:36.643840+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2020-06-15T16:57:36.643840+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
2020-06-15T16:57:36.643840+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
2020-06-15T16:57:36.643840+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2020-06-15T16:57:36.643844+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'
2020-06-15T16:57:36.643961+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-06-15 16:57:36 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2020-06-15T16:57:36.688957+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-06-15 16:57:36 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2020-06-15T16:57:36.689084+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-06-15 16:57:36 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2020-06-15T16:57:36.769273+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2020-06-15T16:57:36.812276+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-06-15T16:57:47.686749+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=alert-model.herokuapp.com request_id=05448fbc-df6f-4e2b-9455-b9ee8d21aac7 fwd="87.201.22.27" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-06-15T16:57:48.409167+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=alert-model.herokuapp.com request_id=1ff4fac0-9a6a-493c-a7d9-8d4a907f49d1 fwd="87.201.22.27" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-06-15T16:57:48.413693+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=alert-model.herokuapp.com request_id=17de52bb-5b1d-4dea-b820-b038ccc7a0c7 fwd="87.201.22.27" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** I figured it out. The problem was that my file was saved as app.ipynb. I saved it as a .py file and it worked.